# Stuck with mdates.date2num

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to find solution to use `mdates.date2num`, but I still have errors despite trying a few approaches.

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
#from matplotlib.dates import bytespdate2num

'''
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'))
'''

def graph_data(stock):
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0),)

stock_price_url =('http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/+stock+/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv')
source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
stock_data = []
spilt_source = source_code.split('\n')
for line in source_code:
    spilt_line = line.split(',')
    if len(spilt_line) == 6:
        if 'values' not in line and 'labels' not in line:
            stock_data.append(line)

date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(
    stock_data,
    delimiter=',',
    unpack=True,
    # %Y = Full year. 2015
    # %y = partial year 15
    # %m = number of month
    # %d = number day
    # %H = hours
    # %M = minutes
    # %S = seconds
    converters={0: mdates.date2num('%Y%m%d')})
    #converters={0: datefunc})

ax1.plot_date(date, closep, '-', label='Price')
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklables():
    label.set_rotation(45)

plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Interesting Graph')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


graph_data('TSLA')
```

As comments show, I've tried to do several things for this without success.
I am using Python 3 with pyCharm.

Comment: I already correct the line indent but still have errors as below:

line 50, in <module>
    graph_data('TSLA')

line 36, in graph_data
    converters={0: mdates.date2num('%Y%m%d')})

line 362, in date2num
    return _to_ordinalf_np_vectorized(d)

line 2218, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

line 2281, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)

ine 2243, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)

Comment: [`matplotlib.dates.date2num(d)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.‌​html#matplotlib.date‌​s.date2num) expects a datetime object not a string.

Comment: so, can you help me to correct the code?

Comment: Since I don't have your data and I don't know how it looks like, unfortunately, I can't. For getting help, it's somehow crucial to provide a [MCVE].